# How to pass a string to a different method

Tags: java, string, swing, variables, methods

So I am practicing writing programs with several methods, breaking parts of the program into many methods, but I have encountered a problem..

```
public static String askForName()
{
   return JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");
} // END askForName
```

I created this method to allow user to enter their name. This is called in a previous method. Now i want the input box to show up only ONCE to store the string for later use, but I dont know how to do it without it asking again. Is their a another method I can write to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the help from both who answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store it into a variable. Something like this:

```
private String name;

public String getName()
{
 if (name == null)
  askForName();   
 return name;
}

private void askForName()
{
 name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");
}
```

This way, when you call getName(), the dialog will be shown only if the name variable was not already set.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
public void printString(String s){
    System.out.println(s);

}
```

Execute it by:

```
Class.printString(Class.askForName());
```